# SQL Login Failed [2800] with Windows Authentication Only when Using pyodbc, and Only for Certain Databases

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

**Thank you for taking the time to look at my question!**

I have a class `ODBCSources` which returns a SQLAlchemy/pyodbc engine for use with pretty much anything you could want it for. While logged in as a user with database editing permissions and using windows authentication, the code works for some databases on `myserver.mycompany.local` but not one database in particular. The problem database was created a week or so ago vs years ago for the ones that I can connect to with pyodbc. As the same user, I am able to log into the all of the databases using windows authentication + SSMS, Azure Data Studio, and/or DataGrip.

My code works for other databases on the same server, so I don't think the issue is with my connection string (**But, the connection string must have a database name component, not an ODBC name component -- See my answer below**). Additionally, the MS ODBC Data Source Administrator gives the feel good 'TESTS COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY!' message when I test the connection corresponding to the problem database.

Is there a SQL-Server setting that I need to enable to allow python connections to the problem database? (**No -- See my answer below**)

```py
import getpass
import pyodbc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

class ODBCSources():
    """
    A class to return sql alchemy engine for use in something like `pd.to_sql`
    """

    def __init__(self, login = False):
            self.sources = pyodbc.dataSources().keys()
            self.login = login
            self.user = ""
            self.pwd = ""

    def make_engine(self, odbc_source, driver = 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'):

        if odbc_source not in self.sources:
            raise ValueError(f'{odbc_source} is not available.\nAvailable Sources: {self.sources}')

        else:
            if self.login:
                # This just gets the currently logged in user. Not really much more flexible
                # than windows auth, but I'm not concerned with this
                user = getpass.getuser()
                pwd = getpass.getpass()
                engine = create_engine(f'mssql+pyodbc://{user}:{pwd}@myserver.mycompany.local/{odbc_source}?driver={driver}', echo = False)
            else:
                user = self.user
                pwd = self.pwd
                engine = create_engine(f'mssql+pyodbc://{user}:{pwd}@myserver.mycompany.local/{odbc_source}?driver={driver}', echo = False)

        return engine
```

Comment: Can we assume that the troublesome database does not have a name that contains"funny" characters (i.e., ones that might require URL escaping)?

Comment: Yes the name of the troublesome database name consists of (I am sort of abusing regex) `[A-Za-z_]*` and the odbc connection name consists of `[a-z]*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue by creating a new ODBC datasource having a the same name as my database . . . which was really not necessary at all, but led me to the root cause root cause of my issue: my connection string is suitable for connection via database names, not ODBC names.

It so happened that in the past I created all of my ODBC connections with the same name as their corresponding database, so I was able to get by thinking that my connection string in `create_engine` had an ODBC component (it does not), because I was actually entering correct database names.